# What are the limitations of uploading videos in android development?

Tags: android, upload, video-capture, asyncfileupload

I am going to develop an app to upload images and videos to a remote server. So I need to know what the limitations of uploading videos by android application are?

Comment: I guess the only limitaions is internet connection and AOS device storage size from where you probably will upload a file...

Comment: What sorts of "limitations" are you looking for?

Comment: such as limit of file size